# Show $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot x^{2n+1}}{n!} = x \cdot \text{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have to show that the following are equivalent:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot x^{2n+1}}{n!}
=
x \cdot \text{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4n^2+2n) \cdot (-1)^n \cdot 2^{-n} \cdot x^{2n-1}}{n!}
=
x \cdot (x^2-3) \cdot \text{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
$$
I know that the following is true:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\text{e}^x
$$
But I don't know how to work with it. I hope i can get some help to solve this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ummm... what's the difference between the two terms in the title?

Comment: I have changed it now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plug in values for the power series.  For example, if you have

$$e^x = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{x^n}{n!}}$$

plug in $(-x^2)/2$ in place of $x$ to get

$$\begin{align}
e^{-(x^2/2)} &= \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-(x^2/2))^n}{n!}} \\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n(x^2/2)^n}{ n!}} \\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^n 2^{-n} x^{2n}}{ n!}}
\end{align}$$

Now the original series asked for $x \cdot e^{(-x^2)/2}$, and you now have $e^{(-x^2)/2}$.    I'm sure you can figure out how to multiply the series on the right and by $x$.

Can you do the second problem?  It's actually just more arithmetic.

Comment: I don't know if I have done it right, but when I solve the second problem I get the following: $x \cdot (x^2-3) \cdot \text{e}^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-n} \cdot (-1)^n \cdot (x^3-3x)\cdot x^{2n}}{n!}$, and that is not equal to the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-n} \cdot (-1)^n \cdot (4n^2+2n) \cdot x^{2n-1}}{n!}$, i don't know if that matter

Comment: @TarekBadr:  Did you get the correct result for the first problem?  Work on that one first.  For the second problem, use your answer to the first problem...  You're just multiplying the result $x \cdot e^{(-x^2)/2}$ by $x^2 - 3$.  So you can just multiply your result for the first problem by $x^2 - 3$.  Then, you have to use some knowledge about summations to rearrange this new sum.

Comment: Yes I did :), but I can't figure out how to rearrange the new sum: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-n} \cdot (-1)^n \cdot (x^3-3x) \cdot x^{2n}}{n!}$ to make it equal to the sum: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-n} \cdot (-1)^n \cdot (4n^2+2n) \cdot x^{2n-1}}{n!}$

Comment: @TarekBadr:  Ok, so you multiply the first sum by $(x^2 - 3)$.  That is the same as multiplying the first sum by $(x^2)$ to get one sum, call it #1, and then again by $-3$ to get a second sum, call it #2.  Then you have to use knowledge about summations to combine them.  #1 has the term $x^{2n+1}$ in place of $x$.  Do you see how this happens?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome!